# optimizing my.cnf for my server - database using all RAM

Tags: centos, mysql, wordpress

I have a vps with 12GB RAM. Currently it has one wordpress website hosted.
The website gets about 10k UV a day with about 30k views according to Jetpack.

I am getting alot of error establishing a database connection errors.

Here is my my.cnf file: ( I know I may have done something wrong, but I copied the file from the internet and added it to my server)

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
[client]
port=3306
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
log-bin=mysql-bin
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
expire_logs_days=7
query_cache_size=128M
thread_cache_size=12
max_allowed_packet=15M
skip-federated
table_definition_cache=2048
local-infile=0
table_open_cache=8192
max_connections=60
read_buffer_size=2M
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="/var/log/slow_queries.log"
thread_concurrency=16
sort_buffer_size=2M
port=3306
join_buffer_size=16M
key_buffer_size=600M
query_cache_limit=10M
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
skip-external-locking
query-cache-type=1
long_query_time=5
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
tmp_table_size=384M
max_heap_table_size=384M

[myisamchk]
read_buffer=2M
key_buffer=256M
sort_buffer_size=256M
```

and this is the output of mysqltuner.pl:

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.35-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err(1M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err exists
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err contains 3340 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err contains 22 error(s).
[--] 6 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err
[--] 1) 2017-05-21 20:34:30 16325 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2017-05-21 20:19:27 11180 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2017-05-21 20:03:04 7569 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2017-05-21 19:49:21 5230 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2017-05-20 06:10:06 713 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2017-05-19 19:37:13 5772 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 15 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err
[--] 1) 2017-05-21 20:29:32 14760 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2017-05-21 20:28:23 13925 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2017-05-21 20:28:19 11180 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2017-05-21 20:14:38 9938 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2017-05-21 20:14:28 9693 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2017-05-21 20:10:17 8761 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2017-05-21 20:10:14 7569 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2017-05-21 20:03:03 5230 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2017-05-21 19:48:03 4757 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2017-05-21 19:47:54 4531 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics ----------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +P        ERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 229K (Tables: 6)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 138M (Tables: 94)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------        -------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations -------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Up for: 20h 22m 22s (3M q [41.069 qps], 61K conn, TX: 13G, RX: 515M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 93% / 7%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 11.6G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 12.3G
[--] Other process memory: 1.4G
[--] Total buffers: 11.1G global + 20.5M per thread (60 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 12.3G (106.49% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 12.3G (106.31% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/3M)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100%  (61/60)
[!!] Aborted connections: 15.70%  (9695/61744)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connect        ion and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 88.9% (2M cached / 2M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 10K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 86% (8K on disk / 10K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (951 created / 61K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 96% (186 open / 193 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (61/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (275K immediate / 275K locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 99.95% (17590 Memory / 17599 Total)

-------- Performance schema -----------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.1% (113M used / 629M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 600.0M/211.0K
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.4% (28K cached / 163 reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 53.2% (8K cached / 4K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 10.0G/138.5M
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (0.9375 %): 48.0M * 2/10.0G s        hould be equal 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.97% (14114607 hits/ 14119114 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 61.48% (39497 hits/ 64247 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 24750 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------        -------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------        -------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/host1.cloudserverpanel.com.err file
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration wit        h skip-name-resolve=1
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Performance should be activated for better diagnostics
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    max_connections (> 60)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
    innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group should be equal to 1/4 of buffer p        ool size (=5G) if possible.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=10)
```

Comment: Have you read the output of Mysqltuner? It has all necessary recommendations for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using too much memory for Mysql and your others process like application server, PHP processor and even Mysql connector are starving.

Without the error logs, I guess that the problem is here:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G
```

Change it for something like the total size of your database (only if your system has a lot of intensive queries).

I would change it for something like 1GB and test the response time with high loads, then increase the value and check it again. Maybe you don't need all that memory reserved for innodb cache.

For a more complete explanation, look here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

You have just mentioned memory of your server, what is the cpu cores etc on the vps ?, first of all when you get error *error establishing a database connection* you should check your memory usage *free -m* and your mysql processlist *show processlist* which will give you an idea of whats going on your system, same time check your process list using top and check for apache process

Also i can see your my.cnf config uses 10 gb for *innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G* out of 12 gb of ram keep in mind you will need memory for other config parameters such as *table_definition_cache=2048* and for other system processes like apache etc

For my.cnf config parameteres you can use [Percona](https://tools.percona.com/sign-in) config tool which will guide you to set the my.cnf config according to your system config, mention only 8 gb out of 12 for mysql as you have apache also which needs memory

Other things which can effect the performance is system hdd speed and network bandwidth